# Loading a model once instead of each time I call the image detection script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a very simple API that predicts the presence, or not, of unsafe driving behaviors. In addition to identifying the non-regularity of the behavior, the API allows to characterize the infraction committed.

The API also allows to generate a heat map to locate which part of the image allowed the models to make their predictions.

So far, the API loads the ClassificationModel model every time we ask for it on the image passed through the script. How to load the model only once?

`main.py`

```
from model import ClassificationModel
import argparse
import os


def predict_img(img_path, with_heatmap=False):
    model = ClassificationModel() <--- Aqui descargo el modelo cada vez que llamo a predict_img

    row = model.predict(img_path=img_path, row=None, img=None, load=True, original_image_path=img_path,
                        print_heatmap=with_heatmap)

    results = row.to_json()
    print(results)

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--path", "-p", help="path of the image", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--heatmap", "-heat", help="generate heatmap or not", required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not(os.path.exists(args.path)):
        raise FileNotFoundError("{} does not exist.".format(args.path))

    elif args.path.split(".")[-1] not in ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]:
        raise TypeError("The file is not a valid image file.")

    if args.heatmap.upper() == "TRUE":
        args.heatmap = True
    else:
        args.heatmap = False

    result = predict_img(img_path=args.path, with_heatmap=args.heatmap)
```

`model.py`

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(40)
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

import settings as st

from predict import Predict


class ClassificationModel(Predict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_pos = [
            "safe driving",
            "texting - right",
            "talking to the phone - right",
            "texting - left",
            "talking on the phone - left",
            "operating the radio",
            "drinking",
            "reaching behind",
            "hair and makeup",
            "talking to passenger"
        ]

        self.image_size = 384
        self.generator = ImageDataGenerator(brightness_range=[0.7, 1.5],
                                            rotation_range=35,
                                            fill_mode='nearest',
                                            zoom_range=0.125,
                                            rescale=1. / 255)

        self.model = load_model(st.model_path)
        self.threshold = 0.5
        self.n_step = 5
        self.normal_index = 0
```

Comment: You can create script with infinite loop which waits for some input data via http/sockets

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kacpo1 I guess I can start with this while True at the very beginning of the main function in main.py. However I have no clue about how to wait for some input data via http/sockets. How would you implement it?

Comment: I would probably use `flask` server for this, Load model at the start of the script and do inference when you recieve specified request with image data in it. Flask module it probably one of the easiest module for python http servers. Also you can try even smaller module called `http.server`.